# Estimation of $\phi$ in $AR(1)$ process

Tags: time-series, self-study, estimation, arima

> Let $n=144$ observations from an $AR(1)$ model $$y_t=\phi
>  y_{t-1}+\epsilon_t$$ where $\epsilon_t$ is White Noise with mean zero
>   and variance $\sigma^2$. If $y_1=-1.7$, $y_{144}=-2.1$, $\sum_{t=2}^n
>  y_t y_{t-1}=-128.6$ and $\sum_{t=1}^n y_t^2=246.4$.
>
> Find an estimate for $\phi$.

I already found that the estimate of $\phi$ is the first sample autocorrelation [Time Series Analysis: With Applications in R](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387759581)
$$\hat{\phi}=\frac{\sum_{t=2}^n (y_t-\overline{y})(y_{t-1}-\overline{y})}{\sum_{t=1}^n (y_{t-1}-\overline{y})^2}$$

The problem is that I don't know how to evaluate it just with the information that I have.

$$\hat{\phi}=\frac{\sum_{t=2}^n (y_t y_{t-1}-\overline{y}y_{t}+\overline{y}y_{t-1}+\overline{y}^2)}{\sum_{t=1}^n (y_t^2-2\overline{y}y_{t-1}+\overline{y}^2)}$$

I have separated the sums but it seems to me that the information is insufficient. What I'm missing?

Comment: Hint: OLS estimation minimizes $\sum(y_t-\phi y_{t-1})^2$. Take the first derivative of that with respect to $\phi$ and set it equal to zero, and you will understand why the formula you posted is not the appropriate one, for this particular specification. Careful with the indices.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos In this case $\overline{y}=0$ and you have $\hat{\phi}=\frac{\sum_{t=2}^n y_t y_{t-1}}{\sum_{t=1}^n y_t^2}$. This formula that I posted is just for nonzero mean process right?

Comment: Careful with the indices. What is the index run in the objective function to be minimized?

Comment: Yes the general formula is for an $AR(1)$ with drift (and so non-zero mean).

Comment: Have you checked that the absolute value of of the estimate for phi is less than 1.  Phi needs to be less than 1 in absolute value for stationarity.

Comment: @MichaelChernick If $\hat{\phi}=\frac{\sum_{t=2}^n y_t y_{t-1}}{\sum_{t=1}^n y_t^2}=\frac{-128.6}{246.4}=-0.52$. I used what they give, but the index run looks little strange.

Comment: You start from a single sum (the objective function), so you have to have a single index run... this is why they gave you the value for $y_1$ separately.

Comment: I don't like the statement that the answer has to be the first lag sample autocorrelation estimate.  It presupposes that there is only one estimate for phi.  Even in terms of maximum likelihood there are two estimates when you have only a finite realization of the stochastic process.  You have the conditional likelihood to maximize of the full likelihood.  They don.t necessarily lead to the same answer.  Also the only two observations that you know are y_1 and y_144.  What does that tell you about a solution? I think the fact that you cannot reconstruct the entire set of observations matters.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Why are you requesting the OP to provide his own answer? Our hands are tied because this is self study.  So we can only provide hints and not complete answers.  But at this point the OP appears to still be puzzled and not know the answer.

Comment: @MichaelChernick I provided the OP with enough hints to solve this. Then exactly because it is a self study and "our hands are tied" as regards posting an answer, I suggested that  he should offer the community a service by posting himself the answer and accept it.

Comment: @MichaelChernick As regards alternative estimators, they certainly exist, but the data provided to the OP hint clearly towards using OLS estimation. And the OP is required to find _some_ estimate for $\phi$ given what he's got.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos I agree with you on the outline of the solution and all your remarks related to the substance of the problem.  I have difficulty with the SE/CV rules regarding self study tagged problems.

Comment: @MichaelChernick You're not the only one!

Comment: We can see below that the OP has given an answer that he is not sure of and intends to try to find another one that might be better.  Should the OP be rewarded for a correct answer or downvoted for an incorrect one?  Other options that I don't like are for someone other than the OP to give an answer or supply one in comments.  This leads to the suggestion that such questions should only include hints and no answers. Now your argument is that a good answer from the OP might be a service to the community.  Possibly this should be a discussion topic on meta.

Answer (score 3):

Following what @Alecos said

The OLS estimation minimizes
$$\sum_{t=2}^n (y_t-\phi y_{t-1})^2=\sum_{t=2}^n (y_t^2-2\phi y_t y_{t-1}+\phi^2 y_{t-1}^2)$$
Taking derivative

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}\sum_{t=2}^n (y_t^2-2\phi y_t y_{t-1}+\phi^2 y_{t-1}^2)=-2\sum_{t=2}^n y_t y_{t-1}+2\phi\sum_{t=2}^n y_{t-1}^2=0$$
Then
$$\hat{\phi}=\frac{\sum_{t=2}^n y_t y_{t-1}}{\sum_{t=2}^ny_{t-1}^2}$$

In this way the denonimator goes from $1$ to $(n-1)$, so theoretically I have to take $$\sum_{t=1}^n y_t^2-y_{144}^2=246.4-(-2.1)^2=241.99$$

Then $$\hat{\phi}=\frac{-128.6}{241.99}\approx 0.53$$

Comment: Indeed. The question is why they provided you also with the value of $y_1$... perhaps as a little trap (that I could not resist applying it in my related previous comment!).

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos This question has another item involving covariance in prediction errors, maybe this is what I'm going to use, but I'll try first before posting.

Comment: @Roland Maybe that should be a separate question for you to pose.  Are you satisfied with your answer here?

Comment: @MichaelChernick I do not know what you mean by "satisfied", I just want to learn how to resolve the question, however I do not see other possible solutions based on what was provided, but every suggestion is welcome.

Comment: It appears to me that you might be using the site to confirm your answer to a homework or quiz problem. The question is so specific that it is hard to believe that there is a point for additional suggestions.