# How do I find my coefficient for AR(1)

Tags: estimation, autoregressive, augmented-dickey-fuller

I've been working on trying to create an AR model for the unemployment rate in the USA.
I started with de-trending etc to make my data stationary, then tested with a dickey fuller test to make sure there wasn't a unit root.
I like to do the calculations manually instead of using some software as it allows me to fully understand.

The Dickey Fuller test can be written as the following equation:

[image]

With the following general AR equation:
[image]

Therefore to be able to calculate the Dickey Fuller test we need to find an estimation of pi, or the coefficient we are interested in minus 1. (That's the definition of the pi with the little hat, an estimation of pi)

To get this estimation we just plot delta Yt against Yt-1, and use the least-squares method to find the gradient, which in this case is pi.

So my question is, can I then not just solve for the phi coefficient? Can I not just use the estimated pi coefficient? Or do I need to use another method to calculate the actual coefficient.

Also for the general formula of an AR model:

[image]

Would my computer program just plug in random error values (et)? Or do I need to determine the range or variance of the white noise? If so how do I calculate the white noise characteristics?

Comment: Most models assume the errors are Normally Distributed with a center of zero, so we generalize to $Y_t = \varphi Y_{t-1}$. Knowing your error variance is important for understanding your model and projections, but not necessary for solving for $\varphi$ here

Comment: @jros Thanks a lot! However, just doing a regular linear regression is enough to find the coefficient? How else would I do it?

Comment: have you seen this post already? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253833/estimation-of-phi-in-ar1-process

Comment: Thank You @jros!

Comment: @jros regarding what you said about the normally distributed, so it would be a NID(0,....) what would the variance value be, the variance is specific to each model no? if so how do I calculate it? Thank You

Comment: you are correct that the variance would be specific to the model, and can be approximated by calculating the variance of the residuals of the model's predictions (usually on a test set)